# How to estimate probabilty for count data where each count occurs only one time?

Tags: probability, count-data, poisson-regression

I would like to estimate probability of labor mobility from one industry to another one. As an outcome variable I took number of hiring and explanatory variables are separations, differences in wages between sectors, age of workers and etc. For example, there were 20 000 hiring in food sector. I need to estimate probability that these people came from textile or machinery sectors depending on separations in textile and machinery sectors as well as differences in wages between food and textile industry, food and machinery industry.

I know that in this case I should use Poisson regression (or negative binomial in case of over-dispersion) as my outcome variable is count. But the problem is that in each sector number of hiring is unique number, so the frequency of outcome variable is the same. Can I use in this case Poisson regression?

Here is my first 10 observations of outcome variable (hiring):

[image]

Comment: Why are you taking note of the fact that `33559` occurred only once, eg? AFAICT, that is your count, not 1.

Comment: @gung If I understand you correctly, I agree with you. But why in this case  r shows _NaN value for X-Squared and N/A for p-value_ when I estimate Chi-Square Goodness of Fit Test to test whether my outcome variable comes from the Poisson or negative binomial distributions. I thought this test uses frequences of count data. If it uses frequences, probability is the same for all observations and this is a discrete uniform distribution.

Comment: Why are you running a chi-squared GoF test? That makes no sense. The way you fit a Poisson regression in R is `model <- glm(count~covariates, family=poisson)`.

Comment: @gung shouldn´t I check first of all what type of distribution fits my outcome variable?

Comment: You know they're counts. What is there to check? When you fit the model, you can check for overdispersion.